# How to separate symbols from text with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textNode in which i have the data coming like this `data=$(2000)%`,so i want to separate out the symbols and number.

```
let preText = ''
let number = ''
let postText = ''
let data = '$(2000)%'

const regex = new RegExp(`(\(\[)?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{1,3})*(\.[0-9]{1,5})?(\)\])?`); 

data.match(regex)

Output expected:
preText = '$('
number = '2000'
postText = ')%'
```

Another example: if `data=$2,23,603`, the output should be `preText=$`, `number=2,23,603` and `postText=`.

I'm not able to achieve this with different variables,how can i get the desired output?

Comment: `[preText, number, postText] = data.split(/(\d+)/)`

Comment: Judging by your pattern, a better test string would be `'$(52,000.5617)%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const data = '$(2000)%';
const regex = /^(.*?)((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,5})?)(\D.*)?$/; 
const [_, preText, number, postTex] = data.match(regex);
console.log([preText, number, postTex]);
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (`preText`): any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,5})?)` - Group 2 (`number`): one to three digits followed with zero or more occurrences of a comma and one to three digits, or just one or more digits, and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one to five digits
- `(\D.*)?` - Group 3 (`postTex`), optional: a non-digit char and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this deals with it properly but there i an issue if `data=$2,23,603` the output comes as `preText=$` `number=2` and postText=`,23,603` instead it should be `number=2,23,603` and `postText=" "`

Comment: @SDP As I said, your sample input could be a bit more specific and consistent with your pattern. Just use your `,\d{1,3}` then. See the updated pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes about the pattern:

- First testing you code, this is the error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(([)?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{1,3})*(.[0-9]{1,5})?()])?/: Unterminated group

- Apart from that, you have to double escape the backslash in the RegExp constructor
- Between the parenthesis, there is 2000 which is 4 digits, and `[0-9]{1,3}` can only match 1-3 digits.
- A pattern like `\(\[` will only match when both `([` are present
- The pattern does not match `$` or `%` so that can not be in the output

What you could do it either capture all the possible symbols in groups on the left and the right using a character class like `[$\[(]`

```
([$\[(]*)\b((?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{1,3})*(?:\.[0-9]{1,5})?)|\d+)\b([\])%]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XOH7Um/1)

Or optionally match all non digits `\D*` around matching the digits:

```
(\D*)\b((?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{1,3})*(?:\.[0-9]{1,5})?)|\d+)\b(\D*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zqrd8T/1)

If there is a match, the capture group numbers are 1, 2 and 3:

```js
let data = '$(2000)%'
const regex = /([$\[(]*)\b((?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{1,3})*(?:\.[0-9]{1,5})?)|\d+)\b([\])%]*)/;
const m = data.match(regex);
console.log(m);

if (m) {
  preText = m[1];
  // etc..
}
```